# Proof of Karlin-Rubin's theorem

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, st.statistics

I asked this question on Math Exchange, but as I did not receive a successful answer, maybe you could help me.

Karlin-Rubin's theorem states conditions under which we can find a uniformly most powerful test (UMPT) for a statistical hypothesis:

> Suppose a family of density or mass functions $\{f(\vec{x}|\theta):\,\theta\in\Theta\}$ and we want to test $$\begin{cases} H_0:\,\theta\leq\theta_0 \\ H_A:\,\theta>\theta_0.\end{cases}$$If the likelihood ratio is monotone on a statistic $T(\vec{x})$ (that is, for every fixed $\theta_1<\theta_2$ in $\Theta$, the ratio $\frac{f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)}{f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)}$ is nondecreasing on $\{\vec{x}:\,f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)>0\text{ or }f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)>0\}$ as a function of $T(\vec{x})$, interpreting $c/0=\infty$ if $c>0$), then the test of critical region $\text{CR}=\{\vec{x}:\,T(\vec{x})\geq k\}$, where $k$ is chosen so that $\alpha=P(\text{CR}|\theta=\theta_0)$, is the UMPT of size $\alpha$.

In all the proofs I have read (for instance, in page 22 [here](https://www.soph.uab.edu/sites/edu.ssg/files/People/KZhang/BST695-11Fall/BST695-2011-Fall-Chapter-08.pdf) or in "[Statistical inference](http://people.unica.it/musio/files/2008/10/Casella-Berger.pdf)" by Casella-Berger, 2n edition, page 391), it is (more or less) said: "we can find $k_1$ such that, if $T(\vec{x})\geq k$, then $\frac{f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)}{f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)}\geq k_1$, and if $T(\vec{x})<k$, then  $\frac{f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)}{f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)}< k_1$". I would understand that statement if the likehood ratio were strictly increasing, but what about the case in which it is constant?

For example, if $X\sim U(0,\theta)$, the likelihood ratio is monotone on $T(\vec{x})=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i$ ($n$ is the length of the sample $\vec{x}$), but not strictly increasing.

My questions are:

1. Is the assertion between quotation marks true for every density or mass function with (not strictly) monotone likelihood ratio on $T$?
2. And what about in the case of the uniform distribution?

Comment: (1)Yes but it will be uninteresting since its critical function will be equivalent to $\phi\equiv\alpha$ (2) Uniform family does not have common support so you have to re-define likelihood ratio. Pfanzagl proved that the UMP test for the form of hypotheses specified above only exists for one-dim regular exp families.

Comment: See http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387988641 chapter 3 for details.

Comment: Link to the question on math.SE: [Proof of Karlin-Rubin's theorem, detail about a real analysis fact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2086051)

Comment: You might want to try here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\th\theta\newcommand\al\alpha$Even the following more general assertion is true:

> Suppose that there is a statistic $T$ such that for all $\th_0$ and $\th_1$ such that $\th_0<\th_1$ there is a nondecreasing function $g_{\th_0,\th_1}$ such that for all $x$ we have
> $$r_{\th_0,\th_1}(x):=\frac{f_{\th_1}(x)}{f_{\th_0}(x)}=g_{\th_0,\th_1}(T(x)).$$
> Suppose that a test $\phi$ is such that for some real $k$ and all $x$
> $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1&\text{ if }T(x)>k, \\ 
> 0&\text{ if }T(x)<k 
> \end{cases}$$
> (the test $\phi$ may be randomized, taking any value $\phi(x)$ in the interval $[0,1]$ if $x$ is such that $T(x)=k$).
> Then the test $\phi$ is uniformly most powerful of level $\al:=E\phi(X)$ for the hypotheses as in the OP.

This follows because, for $c:=g_{\th_0,\th_1}(k)$, we have the implications $$r_{\th_0,\th_1}(x)>c\iff g_{\th_0,\th_1}(T(x))>c\implies T(x)>k\implies\phi(x)=1\tag{1}$$
(so that $H_0$ is rejected by the test $\phi$) and
$$r_{\th_0,\th_1}(x)<c\iff g_{\th_0,\th_1}(T(x))<c\implies T(x)<k\implies\phi(x)=0\tag{2}$$
(so that $H_0$ is not rejected by the test $\phi$) -- which means that $\phi$ is a [Neyman--Pearson test](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Elmackey/stats300a/doc/stats300a-fall15-lecture13.pdf)for any $\th_0$ and $\th_1$ such that $\th_0<\th_1$.

That $T$ is not strictly increasing causes no problems whatsoever, because in (1) and (2) we only need the left-to-right implications.

Answer (score 0):

If it were to be constant then the statistical model $\{f(\vec{x}|\theta):\,\theta\in\Theta\}$ would only contain copies of the same density, i.e. one single density. In this case, inference is quite useless, but nonetheless the test is UMPT (and unbiased) since power and size agree for every test.

Comment: But I mean constant around $k$, not everywhere (as in the case of $U(0,\theta)$, which is piecewise constant). The thing is that, if the likelihood ratio is constant around $k$, it is not true (I think) that "we can find $k_1$ such that, if $T(\vec{x})\geq k$, then $f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)/f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)\geq k_1$, and if $T(\vec{x})< k$, then $f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)/f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)< k_1$". So, why is that assertion written in all proofs?

Comment: The thing is that if for $\theta_1<\theta_2$ we have a constant likelihood ratio around $k$ then one density is $k$ times the other. Since they both integrate to $1$, then necessarily $k=1$ and the densities are equal.

Comment: I see this: Let $\theta_1<\theta_2$. We have $$\frac{f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)}{f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)}=g_{\theta_1,\theta_2}(T(\vec{x})),$$ where $g=g_{\theta_1,\theta_2}$ is monotone and constant around the point $k\in \mathbb{R}$. That is, there is an $r>0$ such that $g|_{]k-r,k+r[}=C=\text{constant}$. Then $f(\vec{x}|\theta_2)=C\,f(\vec{x}|\theta_1)$ for all $\vec{x}\in T^{-1}(]k-r,k+r[)$. The set of equality is not the whole $\mathbb{R}$ so I cannot integrate. And $C$ is not $k$.